# How to repeat simple jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Trying to adapt snook.ca's [Simplest jQuery Slides](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) for multiple, nested elements. I've got the cycle working, although I'm sure my jQuery is a bit verbose. I can't, however, figure out how to return the script to the beginning of the set of elements so it repeats an endless loop. Snook's script uses appendTo to return to the beginning and re-create the stack but I'm lost as to how to put this

Here is the HMTL (there are 4 (fixed) instances of these list items):

```
<li class="current">
  <h3>...</h3>
  <p><img src="..."><span>...<a href="...">...</a></span></p>
</li>
```

And here is the jQuery (it's the `<p>` elements which are being cycled):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('header nav li').not('.current').children('p').hide();
     setInterval(function(){
   $('header nav li.current').children('p')
       .hide().parent('li').removeClass().next('li')
       .addClass('current').children('p').show().end();
       },3000);
 });
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: I don't quite follow your markup.

So each &lt;li&gt; has an &lt;h3&gt; in it, but you are only cycling the &lt;p&gt; element? What happens to the &lt;h3&gt;? Does it just continually show the first one? And if so, why have it inside the li? Why not put it before the list?

Comment: @iboxifoo I voted to close this as an exact duplicate so just your new question will be used since it has the links, etc. In the future, just edit your original question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!